# R Not Consistently Incrementing Excel Values in For Loop?

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to create a for loop in R that will increment the values in a column that's being read from Excel. The problem is, it sometimes inconsistently increments values; sometimes it will increment to 1 but then won't increment the second time, other times it increments to 2 but won't increment to 3. It's very puzzling because it can't be consistently reproduced. Here is the code I am using:

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel(imported_data)
increment <- function(){
  for (x in 6:nrow(data)){
   data$Column[x] <<- data$Column[x] + 1
   print(data$Column[x])
  }
}
repeat{
  function()
}
```

I'm trying to make it consistently increment it every time, but it just simply won't increment it consistently. I'm wondering if maybe there is somehow an issue with reading the data, because it's very weird that it can't be consistently reproduced.

EDIT: This is the DPut output. I am trying to increment daysWithoutFood, but it isn't consistenly adding. (Sorry for the imgur link, I don't know how to paste the dput() output here without it looking really messy, I'm new to this site)
EDIT 2: The messy DPut output

```
structure(list(Name = c("Andrew", "Kenny", "Jonathan", "Seawars", 
"Alex", "Eric", "Youngi"), Strength = c(9, 9, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9), 
    Speed = c(7, 7, 2, 7, 0, 7, 4), Shooting = c(4, 2, 9, 6, 
    9, 7, 5), Medical = c(9, 4, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9), Cooking = c(2, 
    4, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6), Construction = c(0, 4, 8, 6, 7, 2, 6), 
    Botany = c(6, 4, 7, 1, 6, 5, 2), DaysSleptOutside = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Injury = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Alive = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE), DaysInjured = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), DaysWithoutFood = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: This is confusing because you use `data$Column[x]` and it is not clear if all columns are named Column6, Column7, Column8...or if you are trying to extract a column of data using integer slicing. Can you `dput(head(data))` to show us what the data itself looks like?

Comment: I updated the original post with the dput(head(data)), if that helps

Comment: Please include that messy-looking output to your question, you can include it in a code block, but try to avoid any additional editing/formatting of `dput()` output --  it does not have to look good, it helps us to understand the structure of your data, reproduce the issues you are having and test answers. Besides, your added screenshot is lacking that column.

Comment: the reason for including the copied text instead of a photograph is that we can ingest it directly into R if you do, no one is going to type the table in to be of use to you

Comment: Perfect edit and that's exactly what we are looking for! To add 1 to every value in `DaysWithoutFood` column, all you need is `data$DaysWithoutFood <- data$DaysWithoutFood + 1`

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a few things that I see as problematic

1. `or (x in 6:nrow(data)` creates a range of numbers, not column names. So, to use those number in R affectively to select a column you need to use appropriate slicing grammar.

   `data[6]` returns the sixth column in a column format, with header information
   `data[[6]]` returns a vector of the values from column six in order
   `data[,6] likewise returns a vector of the values from six in order` data[1,6] returns the first row value in column six
   `data$Column[6] IS NOT R grammar, so if you are expecting data to be returned you will be disappointed.
2. You have a couple of other potential problems in this code, namely the way the data is created outside of the function, and then allowed to be lazily passed into the function when called. It may, but it also may not.

R scoping searches in this order:

- The function environment for something named data
- The last imported package, then the one before it, then the one before it
- Then the global environment where `data` was created

So anything named `data` between that function and your global environment would be tried instead. You should create your function to take the data as an argument:

```
increment <- function(df){
  for (x in 6:nrow(data)){
   data$Column[x] <<- data$Column[x] + 1
   print(data$Column[x])
  }
}
```

then call it with the data which you want it to use, in this case `data`:

```
increment(data)
```

3. That repeat function does not appear to be useful as constructed here and is completely unnecessary to calling `increment` in this use-case. And even if you need to use it with this function at some point, get rid of it now while you are debugging the base function, it is a distraction from creating a useful function.

Simply fix the method of accessing the columns to return what you need (a vector or 1-column dataframe), explicitly pass a df to the function when you define it and then call the function: `increment(data)`

It should then work

Comment: Wouldn’t it be simpler and faster and more idiomatic to just add 1 to data$DaysWithoutFood like in the comment from @margusl ?

Comment: @JonSpring The comment was probably posted after I wrote this or about the same time. And yes, it would, but I tried to help the original poster learn about what they were doing instead of just saying, "all you have to do is" And also, I do not assume anything about why they are doing what they are doing